# Run video according to URL

Tags: php, html

I need help. I have a file "video.php"
Where it contains an html5 player.

I want instead

**www.mysite.com/myvideo.mp4**

Be it

**Www.mysite.com/video.php?file=myvideo.mp4**

I want the src of the video to change according to what is typed in the url.

**video.php**

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
  <source src=" **Name typed in the url** " type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: what you want? Do you want to chnage your URL from www.mysite.com/myvideo.mp4 to "Www.mysite.com/video.php?file=myvideo.mp4" ??? So that you can get file name from your URL using $_GET variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $_GET['file']?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do.

I tried a lot not google and I did not find it very thankful